# 4 'div's cannot align horizontally

Tags: html, css, flexbox

the problem is i wanna make 4 boxes align horizontally like cards but it turn out like staircase please help

there are 99 lines so please visit here
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jonathansh1115/hbeg8dp1/)

```
                #first {
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: center;
                    margin-left:10px;
                    margin-top:20px;
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please try this** [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/alfinpaul/tpeqc1xz/)

Remove first,second,third and fourth... nth from css, add these below **.card-container**

```
.card-container {
    float: left;
    width: calc(100%/4);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: baseline;
    align-content: center;
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:36px;
   }
   h1 {
    margin:0;
   }
 
   .card-container {
    perspective:700; 
   }
   .card {
    position:relative;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:200px;
    margin:20px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    transition:all 0.6s ease;
    transform-style:preserve-3d;
   }
   .front, .back {
    background-color:#5677fc;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:200px;
    height:600px;
    backface-visibility:hidden; 
   }
   .back {
    transform:rotateY(180deg);     
   }
   .card:hover {
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
   }
      .card-container {
    float: left;
    width: calc(100%/4);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: baseline;
    align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
     <div class="card-container" id="first">
      <div class="card">
             <div class="front"><h1>hello</h1></div>
                <div class="back"><h1>Goodbye</h1></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="card-container" id="second">
      <div class="card">
             <div class="front"><h1>hello</h1></div>
                <div class="back"><h1>Goodbye</h1></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="card-container" id="third">
      <div class="card">
             <div class="front"><h1>hello</h1></div>
                <div class="back"><h1>Goodbye</h1></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="card-container" id="forth">
      <div class="card">
             <div class="front"><h1>hello</h1></div>
                <div class="back"><h1>Goodbye</h1></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove **first,second,third and fourth... nth** from css, add these below `.card-container`.

```
.card-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

Here is the [result](https://jsfiddle.net/hbeg8dp1/2/)

Hope helps,

Answer (score 0):

You just need one container as a flexbox.

```css
.card-container {
  display: flex;
  perspective: 700;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.front,
.back {
  background-color: #5677fc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 600px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      <h1>hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <h1>Goodbye</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      <h1>hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <h1>Goodbye</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      <h1>hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <h1>Goodbye</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      <h1>hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <h1>Goodbye</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 60px
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 50px
}

.card-container {
  perspective: 700;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.front,
.back {
  background-color: #5677fc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container" id="first">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front">
        <h1>hello</h1></div>
      <div class="back">
        <h1>Goodbye</h1></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-container" id="second">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front">
        <h1>hello</h1></div>
      <div class="back">
        <h1>Goodbye</h1></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-container" id="third">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front">
        <h1>hello</h1></div>
      <div class="back">
        <h1>Goodbye</h1></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-container" id="forth">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front">
        <h1>hello</h1></div>
      <div class="back">
        <h1>Goodbye</h1></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use `flex` because it don't support in `IE9` and older.

I use `float` :

```css
body {
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:36px;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  margin:0;
}

.card-container {
  perspective:700; 
  float: left; 
}

.card {
  position:relative;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:200px;
  margin:20px;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  transition:all 0.6s ease;
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
}

.front, .back {
  background-color:#5677fc;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:200px;
  height:600px;
  backface-visibility:hidden; 
}

.back {
  transform:rotateY(180deg);          
}

.card:hover {
   transform:rotateY(180deg);
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="card-container" id="first">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front"><h1>hello</h1></div>
      <div class="back"><h1>Goodbye</h1></div>
    </div>
  </div>
        
  <div class="card-container" id="second">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front"><h1>hello</h1></div>
      <div class="back"><h1>Goodbye</h1></div>
    </div>
  </div>
        
  <div class="card-container" id="third">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front"><h1>hello</h1></div>
      <div class="back"><h1>Goodbye</h1></div>
    </div>
  </div>
          
  <div class="card-container" id="forth">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front"><h1>hello</h1></div>
      <div class="back"><h1>Goodbye</h1></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hbeg8dp1/11/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a new container arround all card containers and use a flexbox to align all card container horizontally:

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/hbeg8dp1/8/) is a working example.

Here is the code:
HTML:

```
        <div class="card-container" id="first">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="front"><h1>hello</h1></div>
                <div class="back"><h1>Goodbye</h1></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card-container" id="second">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="front"><h1>hello</h1></div>
                <div class="back"><h1>Goodbye</h1></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card-container" id="third">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="front"><h1>hello</h1></div>
                <div class="back"><h1>Goodbye</h1></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card-container" id="forth">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="front"><h1>hello</h1></div>
                <div class="back"><h1>Goodbye</h1></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
                font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size:36px;
            }
            h1 {
                margin:0;
            }
                #first {
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: center;
                    margin-left:10px;
                    margin-top:20px;
                }
                #second {
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: center;
                    margin-left:220px;
                    margin-top:20px;
                }
                #third {
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: center;
                    margin-left:430px;
                    margin-top:20px;
                }
                #forth {
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: center;
                    margin-left:640px;
                    margin-top:20px;
                }
            .card-container {
                perspective:700;    
            }
            .card {
                position:relative;
                color:white;
                text-align:center;
                line-height:200px;
                margin:20px;
                width:200px;
                height:200px;
                transition:all 0.6s ease;
                transform-style:preserve-3d;
            }
            .front, .back {
                background-color:#5677fc;
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
                width:200px;
                height:600px;
                backface-visibility:hidden; 
            }
            .back {
                transform:rotateY(180deg);                  
            }
            .card:hover {
                transform:rotateY(180deg);
            }

      .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class for all divs to style them as they all have same style, so there is no need to write same css four times.

> In Html, `div` comes under the **block level element**, means when you work with more than one div, the next div comes in next line whether there is space in the first line. To make them align at one line use CSS property i.e.- `float: left`

simply replace these lines of your code-

```
             #first {
                  float:left;
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: center;
                    margin-left:10px;
                    margin-top:20px;
                }
                #second {
                  float:left;
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: center;
          margin-left:10px;
                    margin-top:20px;
                }
                #third {
                  float:left;
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: center;
          margin-left:10px;
                    margin-top:20px;
                }
                #forth {
                  float:left;
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: center;
                    margin-left:10px;
                    margin-top:20px;
                }
            .card-container {
                perspective:700;    
            }
```

with these few lines-

```
.card-container {
                float:left;
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: center;
                    margin-left:10px;
                    margin-top:20px;
                perspective:700;    
            }
```